# Scatter plot with linear regression?

Tags: python

I need to graph a scatter plot with a linear regression line. (t vs B or t vs dB). My data posts but not my needed graphs. Please help lol

```
from numpy import zeros
from numpy import linspace as ln
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

B = [22.1, 23.4, 26.1, 27.5, 30.5, 34.4, 36.6]
dB = zeros(7)
Bgraph = zeros(7)
t = ln(0, 6, 7)
for i in range(1, 6):
    dB[i] = B[i] - B[i-1]
    Bgraph[i] = B[i-1]
   
print('')
print (B, Bgraph)
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(Bgraph, dB)
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(Bgraph, dB, 'bo')
print(' ')

print(t, B)
print(' ')

plt.xlabel('B'); plt.ylabel('dB')
filestem = 'growth1_%dsteps' %7
plt.savefig('%s.png' %filestem); plt.savefig('%s.pdf' %filestem)
print('slope = ', slope) 
print('intercept = ', intercept)
plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(t, B, 'bo', t, 22.1*1.102**t)
```

Comment: Hey, try to use `plt.show()` before `plt.savefig()`

Comment: The graphs work. I have a regression line and legend for the t vs B graph but not the t vs dB. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you done a plt.show() at the end ?